# install scala 2.10.4 plugin on scalaide

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I installed scalaIDE on ubuntu. as installed, it has both scala 2.11.6 and 2.10.5 build in. The version I need is 2.10.4. How do I add that version into scalaIDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Scala* -> *Installations*

[image]

Click *Add*. Probably you will already have the version of scala you need in `~/.sbt/boot`. Just choose, name it and click *Ok*.

Reference: [BYOS (Bring Your Own Scala)](http://scala-ide.org/blog/scala-installations.html)

Comment: yep. I found scala 2.10.4 there. The other versions are bundled as eclipse plugins. I am wondering if 2.10.4 can also be bundled that way.